# Pip unable to install Django

Tags: pip

I installed Python and attempted to install Django:

1. ran `Python34\python.exe get-pip.py`
2. when I run `pip install Django==1.6.4`, an error is thrown that pip is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you added the Python scripts folder to your path?

Comment: try adding `C:\Python34\Scripts` to the path, then run pip install Django

Comment: I'm going to add my comment as an answer, because I don't know if @user3614681 saw this or not.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to prepend the python.exe path to the pip script (or any Python script).

```
Python34\python.exe path-to-pip\pip install Django==1.6.4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `pip` by itself from the command line, you would have to add the Python scripts folder to your System PATH. So, you would go to your path and append `C:\Python(python version here)\Scripts` replace `(python version here)` with the version of python you are running, like for example `34`, then run the pip command, and it should work.